# Hacer join en dos tablas en mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo duda sobre una consulta en mysql. Tengo dos tablas, una llamada bajos y la otra llamada galerias. La tabla bajos tiene el campo id y el campo nombre y la tabla galerias tiene el id, el id_bajo y la imagen. Mi duda es la siguiente, ¿sería posible realizar una consulta que me mostrase el nombre del bajo y si existe el id_bajo en la tabla galerias me mostrase la imagen y sino un guión?

He tratado de hacer un join pero solo me muestra los bajos que tienen galeria cosa que no es lo que ando buscando.

Otra opción es hacerlo en dos partes, primero sacar un listado de bajos y una vez con el listado sacar si tiene imagen o no y guardar la imagen o el guión en un array.

Muchas gracias

edit:

tabla bajos

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bajos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bajo` char(50) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `id` (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=67 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;
```

tabla galerias

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `galerias` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_bajo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imagen_horizontal` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Consulta join

```
SELECT b.*, g.*
FROM bajos b, galerias g
WHERE b.id = g.id_bajo
```

Muestra solamente los bajos que tienen galeria, cosa que no quiero.

Si hago está consulta salen más resultados de la cuenta y no me sirve

```
SELECT b.*, g.*
FROM bajos b, galerias g
```

Comment: Podrías poner el código de tu consulta para poder ayudarte de una forma mas acertada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select bajo, IFNULL(imagen_horizontal,'-') imagen
from bajos b
left join galerias g on b.id = g.id_bajo
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Era lo que andaba buscando